# hook the left mouse button down event on any window

Tags: python, pywin32

I want to hook the left mouse button down event on any window, my code as following :

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con


def onMousePressed(self):
    print('onMousePressed', win32gui.GetCursorPos())


def listener():
    windowHandle = win32gui.WindowFromPoint(win32gui.GetCursorPos())
    clickedWindow = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(windowHandle)
    clickedWindow.HookMessage(onMousePressed, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    # print('-------------registerMouseEvent', clickedWindow)


while True:
    listener()
```

However , the `onMousePressed` function was never called when clicked, what is wrong ?

P.S. I know some similar projects such as [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput), [mouse](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse), [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard), just want to know why my code didn't work.